# Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException at View reset button click - D9

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a view that uses exposed filters with a "Reset" button. After searching, when the reset button is clicked, I get to see the below error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Drupal\Core\Form\EnforcedResponseException: in Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm() (line 352 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php).
```

I found this link - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3165919 when searching for the issue but the page doesn't mention any fix/patch for this problem.

What I tried:

In Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder.php file, I commented the below lines buildform() method tentatively:

```
if ($response instanceof Response) {
      throw new EnforcedResponseException($response);
    }
```

Need an actual solution for this. any help?!